# PowerShell equivalent of LINQ Any()?

Tags: linq, powershell

I would like to find all directories at the top level from the location of the script that are stored in subversion.

In C# it would be something like this

```
Directory.GetDirectories(".")
  .Where(d=>Directories.GetDirectories(d)
     .Any(x => x == "_svn" || ".svn"));
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty finding the equivalent of "Any()" in PowerShell, and I don't want to go through the awkwardness of calling the extension method.

So far I've got this:

```
 Get-ChildItem | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | Get-ChildItem -force | ? {$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "_svn" -or $_.Name -eq ".svn"
```

This finds me the `svn` directories themselves, but not their parent directories - which is what I want. Bonus points if you can tell me why adding

```
 | Select-Object {$_.Directory}
```

to the end of that command list simply displays a sequence of blank lines.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To **answer the *immediate* question** with a PowerShell v3+ solution:

```bash
(Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory -Recurse -Depth 2 -Include '_svn', '.svn').Parent.FullName
```

`-Directory` limits the matches to directories, `-Recurse -Depth 2` recurses up to three levels (children, grandchildren, and great-grandchildren), `Include` allows specifying multiple (filename-component) filters, and `.Parent.FullName` returns the full path of the *parent* dirs. of the matching dirs., using [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) (implicitly accessing a collection's *elements'* properties).

<sup>As for the bonus question: `select-object {$_.Directory}` does not work,
because the [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances returned by `Get-ChildItem` have no `.Directory` property, only a `.Parent` property; `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Parent` should have been used.</sup>

<sup>In addition to only returning the property *value* of interest, `-ExpandProperty` also enforces the existence of the property. By contrast, `Select-Object {$_.Directory}` returns a *custom object* with a property literally named `$_.Directory`, whose value is `$null`, given that the input objects have no `.Directory` property; these `$null` values print as empty lines in the console.</sup>

---

As for the more ***general* question** about a **PowerShell equivalent to [LINQ's `.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method**, which indicates [with a Boolean result] whether a given enumerable (collection) has any elements at all / any elements satisfying a given condition:

Natively, **PowerShell offers *no* such equivalent**, but the behavior can be **emulated**:

---

##### Using the **PowerShell v4+ [intrinsic`.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)**:

*Caveat*: This **requires collecting the entire input collection in memory first**, which can be problematic with large collections and/or long-running input commands.

```bash
(...).Where({ $_ ... }, 'First').Count -gt 0
```

`...` represents the command of interest, and `$_ ...` the condition of interest, applied to each input object, where PowerShell's automatic `$_` variable refers to the input object at hand; argument `'First'` ensures that the method returns once the first match has been found.

For example:

```bash
# See if there's at least one value > 1
PS> (1, 2, 3).Where({ $_ -gt 1 }, 'First').Count -gt 0
True
```

---

##### Using the *pipeline*: Testing whether a command produced at least one output object [matching a condition]:

The **advantage of a pipeline-based solution** is that it can **act on a command's output *one by one, as it is being produced*, without needing to collect the entire output in memory first**.

- **If you don't mind that *all* objects are enumerated** - even if you only care if there is *at least one* - use [Paolo Tedesco's helpful extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22090065/45375) to [JaredPar's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499466/powershell-equivalent-of-linq-any/1499486#1499486).
  The down-side of this approach is that you always have to wait for a (potentially long-running) command to finish producing *all* output objects, even though - logically - the determination whether there are *any* output objects can be made as soon as the *first* object is received.
- **If you want to *exit the pipeline* as soon as *one* [matching] object has been encountered**, you have two options:

  - [*Ad-hoc: Easy to understand, but cumbersome to implement*]
    Enclose the pipeline in a **dummy loop** and **use `break` to break out of the pipeline** and that loop (`...` represents the command whose output to test, and `$_ ...` match the condition):

    ```bash
     # Exit on first input object.
     [bool] $haveAny = do { ... | % { $true; break } } while ($false)

     # Exit on first input object that matches a condition.
     [bool] $haveAny = do { ... | % { if ($_ ...) { $true ; break } } } while ($false)
    ```
  - [*Use a PowerShell v3+ self-contained utility function that is nontrivial to implement*]
    See the implementation of **function `Test-Any` below**.
    It can be added to scripts or, for use in interactive sessions, to your `$PROFILE` file.

---

##### PowerShell v3+: Optimized **utility function `Test-Any`**

The function is nontrivial, because **as of PowerShell (Core) v7.2.x, there is no *direct* way to exit a pipeline prematurely**, so a workaround based on .NET reflection and a private type is currently necessary.

If you agree that there should be such a feature, take part in the conversation in [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

```bash
#requires -version 3
Function Test-Any {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ScriptBlock] $Filter,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $InputObject
    )

    process {
      if (-not $Filter -or (Foreach-Object $Filter -InputObject $InputObject)) {
          $true # Signal that at least 1 [matching] object was found
          # Now that we have our result, stop the upstream commands in the
          # pipeline so that they don't create more, no-longer-needed input.
          (Add-Type -Passthru -TypeDefinition '
            using System.Management.Automation;
            namespace net.same2u.PowerShell {
              public static class CustomPipelineStopper {
                public static void Stop(Cmdlet cmdlet) {
                  throw (System.Exception) System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Cmdlet).Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException"), cmdlet);
                }
              }
            }')::Stop($PSCmdlet)
      }
    }
    end { $false }
}
```

- `if (-not $Filter -or (Foreach-Object $Filter -InputObject $InputObject))` defaults to true if `$Filter` wasn't specified, and otherwise evaluates the filter (script block) with the object at hand.

  - The use of `ForEach-Object` to evaluate the filter script block ensures that `$_` binds to the current pipeline object in *all* scenarios, as demonstrated in [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232360/function-does-not-get-binding-when-used-in-module/33240383#33240383).
- The `(Add-Type ...` statement uses an ad-hoc type created with C# code that uses reflection to throw the same exception that `Select-Object -First` (PowerShell v3+) uses internally to stop the pipeline, namely `[System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException]`, which as of PowerShell v5 is still a *private* type.
  Background here:
  [http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/01/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160829015320/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/01/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx)
  *A big thank-you to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for contributing this code in the comments.*

**Examples:**

- `PS> @() | Test-Any false`
- `PS> Get-EventLog Application | Test-Any # should return *right away* true`
- `PS> 1, 2, 3 | Test-Any { $_ -gt 1 }  # see if any object is > 1 true`

---

##### Background information

[JaredPar's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499466/powershell-equivalent-of-linq-any/1499486#1499486) and [Paolo Tedesco's helpful extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499466/powershell-equivalent-of-linq-any/22090065#22090065) fall short in one respect: they don't exit the pipeline once a match has been found, which can be an important optimization.

**Sadly, even as of PowerShell v5, there is no direct way to exit a pipeline prematurely**.
If you agree that there should be such a feature, take part in the conversation in [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

A **naïve** optimization of [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499466/powershell-equivalent-of-linq-any/1499486#1499486) actually shortens the code:

```bash
# IMPORTANT: ONLY EVER USE THIS INSIDE A PURPOSE-BUILT DUMMY LOOP (see below)
function Test-Any() { process { $true; break } end { $false } }
```

- The `process` block is only entered if there's at least one element in the pipeline.

  - Small caveat: By design, *if there's no pipeline at all, the `process` block is still entered, with `$_` set to `$null`*, so calling `Test-Any` *outside* of a pipeline unhelpfully returns `$true`. To distinguish between between `$null | Test-Any` and `Test-Any`, check `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput`, which is `$true` only in a pipeline: <sup>Thanks, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)</sup>
    `function Test-Any() { process { $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput; break } end { $false } }`
- `$true`, written to the output stream, signals that at least one object was found.
- `break` then terminates the pipeline and thus prevents superfluous processing of additional objects. **HOWEVER, IT ALSO EXITS ANY ENCLOSING LOOP - `break` is NOT designed to exit a PIPELINE**<sup>Thanks, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)</sup>
  .

  - If there *were* a command to exit the pipeline, this is where it would go.
  - Note that `return` would simply move on to the *next* input object.
- Since the `process` block unconditionally executes `break`, the `end` block is only reached if the `process` block was never entered, which implies an empty pipeline, so `$false` is written to the output stream to signal that.

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent in PowerShell.  I wrote a blog post about this with a suggestion for a general purpose Test-Any function / filter.

```
function Test-Any() {
    begin {
        $any = $false
    }
    process {
        $any = $true
    }
    end {
        $any
    }
}
```

Blog post: *[Is there anything in that pipeline?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/is-there-anything-in-that-pipeline)*

Comment: This is quite a simple but yet effective answer.

Comment: This answer is more correct than the accepted one. While the accepted one might be more efficient, it is difficult to even find the working answer in all the details and caveats. This one at least has the virtue of being simple enough to see that it is correct in all cases, even if it's not the most efficient.

Answer (score 18):

A variation on @JaredPar's answer, to incorporate the test in the `Test-Any` filter:

```
function Test-Any {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($EvaluateCondition,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $ObjectToTest)
    begin {
        $any = $false
    }
    process {
        if (-not $any -and (& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest)) {
            $any = $true
        }
    }
    end {
        $any
    }
}
```

Now I can write "any" tests like

```
> 1..4 | Test-Any { $_ -gt 3 }
True

> 1..4 | Test-Any { $_ -gt 5 }
False
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer for a nice approach; however, I would point out that the `if` statement need only say `if (& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest) { $any = $true }`

Comment: @msorens: I wanted to avoid evaluating the condition if $any is already true.

Comment: `& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest` does not bind object to `$_`. Yours examples works just because you referencing `$_` from parent scope, which would be `Test-Any` scope in case function defined and executed in the same module or in global state. But if function defined in one module and used from other module of from global state, than you will have wrong value in `$_`. You should use something like this: `ForEach-Object $EvaluateCondition -InputObject $ObjectToTest`.

Comment: @mklement0 Look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33240383) to linked question. Scope of `Test-Any` not necessary will be parent for `$EvaluateCondition` script block.

Comment: @PetSerAl: You are absolutely right; thanks for pointing me to your linked answer, which demonstrates the problem clearly. I've deleted my original comment.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the original LINQ `Any`:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Any($list)
```

Comment: While this works, it requires `$list` to be fully in memory already,  which defeats the purpose of using the streaming PowerShell pipeline: PowerShell cmdlets don't emit lazy `IEnumerable`s, they emit objects one by one _to the pipeline_. If you pass a cmdlet call's output to a .NET method, that call has to _run to completion_ first, which means you could wait for a long time and waste a lot of memory before you get the result; consider `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any((Get-ChildItem / -Recurse))`, for instance (cont'd in next comment).

Comment: (Con'td from previous comment) In cases where you _are_ willing to pay the price of running the command to completion first, you can simply use `(...).Count -gt 0` - no need for LINQ; the latter would only help if you happened to call a .NET method that returns a lazy enumerable.

Comment: When I use `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any(@($true, $false))` I get the error `Cannot find an overload for "Any" and the argument count: "1".`  I think you have to pass in a delegate

Comment: @KyleMit The type needs to be specified `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any([bool[]]@($true,$false))` works as [Any()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1288) is a generic method.  Concretely `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Any([String[]]$list,[Func[string,bool]]{param($n)$n -match "svn$"})` would answer the initial question.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually quite simple - just select first $true (formatted for clarity):

```
[bool] ($source `
        | foreach { [bool] (<predicate>) } `
        | where { $_ } `
        | select -first 1)
```

Alternative way:

```
($source `
        | where { <predicate> } `
        | foreach { $true } `
        | select -first 1)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `[bool]` cast at the top since you already are selecting the first of an enumeration of `bool`s

Comment: No, it's required because you could potentially not select any element and the result will be nothing (null) - the [bool] is making sure you always return true or false regardless.

Comment: It's simpler if you just have `foreach { $true }` at the end (after the `select`) and have the predicate in `where` like normal, rather than combine the two.

Comment: Not sure why this would be simpler. Isn't it will be the same amount of lines?

Comment: It becomes `($source | where { <predicate> } | foreach { $true } | select -first 1)`. This eliminates the casts, makes it more explicit what you're trying to return, and puts the predicate in a more expected part of the pipeline.

Comment: Ok, sounds fair. Added your variant to the answer as alternative.

Comment: Another option: `[bool]($source | where {<predicate>} | select -first 1 | foreach {$true})`; means you only do the `foreach` for 1 element, not all.

Comment: Only this answer has the same feature and speed as the mklement0
 Test-Any https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34800670

Answer (score 5):

My approach now was:

```
gci -r -force `
    | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match "^[._]svn$" } `
    | select Parent -Unique
```

---

The reason why

```
select-object {$_.Directory}
```

doesn't return anything useful is that there is no such property on a `DirectoryInfo` object. At least not in my PowerShell.

---

To elaborate on your own answer: PowerShell can treat most non-empty collections as `$true`, so you can simply do:

```
$svnDirs = gci `
    | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} `
    | ? {
        gci $_.Name -Force `
            | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Name -eq "_svn" -or $_.Name -eq ".svn") }
        }
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` returns both `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` objects :-)

Comment: IMO, this is a better answer than @JaredPar's, because you can test for pipeline being empty as described here.  

I think the answer could be improved by moving the | to the line before, and removing the `.

Comment: I tend to break up my piepelines like this for readability. Might just be a matter of personal taste. But imho it definitely reads better than a 200-character line.

Comment: What Jay means is that a | character at the end of the line automatically continues the code to the next line (just like an open bracket without a closed bracket) so that you don't need to escape the return character.

Comment: Yes, but then I need to look at the *previous* line to know *why* there has been a line break (pipeline, block start, etc.) instead of immediately knowing how the pipeline flows when I see the start of the lines.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing it with a count:

```
$directoryContainsSvn = {
    (Get-ChildItem $_.Name -force | ? {$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "_svn" -or $_.Name -eq ".svn"} | Measure-Object).Count -eq 1
}
$svnDirs = Get-ChildItem | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | ? $directoryContainsSvn
```

Comment: Note that you can use the complete pipeline as a boolean test anyway, since any non-empty collection evaluates to `$true` (except the one that contains `$false` as the only element—but that's of no concern here). Also your test is messed-up because the precedence of `-and` and `-or` mean that you will catch *files* that happen to be named `".svn"` too, since the `PSIsContainer` test only applies when the name matches `"_svn"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can tighten this up a bit:

```
gci -fo | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -and `
            (gci $_ -r -fo | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_ -match '[_.]svn$'})}
```

Note - passing $__.Name to the nested gci is unnecessary. Passing it $_ is sufficent.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following solution:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
   Tests if any object in an array matches the expression

.EXAMPLE
    @( "red", "blue" ) | Where-Any { $_ -eq "blue" } | Write-Host
#>
function Where-Any 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        $Condition,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        $Item
    )

    begin {
        [bool]$isMatch = $False
    }

    process {
      if (& $Condition $Item) {
          [bool]$isMatch = $true
      }
    }

    end {
        Write-Output $isMatch
    }
}

# optional alias
New-Alias any Where-Any
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best method that I found so far (does not iterate over all elements if already found a true, and does not break the pipeline):

From *[LINQ Any() equivalent in PowerShell](https://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/linq-any-equivalent-in-powershell)*

It’s possible to use a built-in $input variable that contains the whole pipeline in a scope of function.

So, the desired code could look like the following:

```
function Test-Any([scriptBlock] $scriptBlock = {$true}, [scriptBlock] $debugOut = $null)
{
    if ($debugOut)
    {
        Write-Host(“{0} | % {{{1}}}” -f $input, $scriptBlock)
    }

    $_ret = $false;
    $_input = ($input -as [Collections.IEnumerator])

    if ($_input)
    {
        while ($_input.MoveNext())
        {
            $_ = $_input.Current;

            Write-Host $_

            if ($debugOut)
            {
                Write-Host(“Tested: [{0}]” -f (&$debugOut))
            }

            if (&$scriptBlock)
            {
                if ($debugOut)
                {
                    Write-Host(“Matched: [{0}]” -f (&$debugOut))
                }

                $_ret = $true
                break
            }
        }
    }

    $_ret
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best answer here is the function proposed by @JaredPar, but if you like one-liners as I do I'd like to propose following **`Any` one-liner**:

```
# Any item is greater than 5
$result = $arr | %{ $match = $false }{ $match = $match -or $_ -gt 5 }{ $match }
```

`%{ $match = $false }{ $match = $match -or YOUR_CONDITION }{ $match }` checks that at least one item match condition.

One note - usually the *Any* operation evaluates the array until it finds the first item matching the condition. But *this code evaluates all items*.

Just to mention, you can easily adjust it to become **`All` one-liner**:

```
# All items are greater than zero
$result = $arr | %{ $match = $false }{ $match = $match -and $_ -gt 0 }{ $match }
```

`%{ $match = $false }{ $match = $match -and YOUR_CONDITION }{ $match }` checks that all items match condition.

Notice, that to check Any you need `-or` and to check All you need `-and`.

Answer (score 1):

I took a more linq-style approach.

I know this question is probably super old.  I used this to accomplish my needs:

```
PS> $searchData = "unn"
PS> $StringData = @("unn", "dew", "tri", "peswar", "pymp")
PS> $delegate =  [Func[string,bool]]{ param($d); return $d -eq $searchData }
PS> [Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$StringData, $delegate)
```

Taken from here:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq/#post-71022-_Toc482783751

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800670/15339544) turned into a cmdlet, it should be compatible with Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7+ (*probably won't work in previous versions*).

The main advantage here is that the `StopUpstreamCommandsException` is stored in a `static` field, meaning, we only need get it thru reflection once per session.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace TestAny
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Any")]
    public sealed class TestAnyCommand : PSCmdlet
    {
        private static Exception s_exception;

        private static readonly List<PSVariable> list = new List<PSVariable>(1);

        private Exception StopUpstreamException
        {
            get
            {
                return s_exception ?? (s_exception = GetException());
            }
        }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public PSObject InputObject { get; set; }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 0)]
        public ScriptBlock Filter { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            list.Clear();
            list.Add(new PSVariable("_", InputObject));
            bool condition = LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo<bool>(
                Filter.InvokeWithContext(null, list)
                    .FirstOrDefault());

            if (condition)
            {
                WriteObject(true);
                throw StopUpstreamException;
            }
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            WriteObject(false);
        }

        private Exception GetException()
        {
            return (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(Cmdlet).Assembly
                    .GetType("System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException"), this);
        }
    }
}' -PassThru | Import-Module -Assembly { $_.Assembly }

0..1mb | Test-Any { $_ -gt 10 }
```