# Exiting the function while in loops like Foreach-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a function like this in Powershell:

```
function F()
{
      $something | Foreach-Object {
           if ($_ -eq "foo"){
                #  Exit from F here
           }
      }
      # do other stuff
}
```

if I use `Exit` in the if statement, it exits powershell, I don't want this behavior. If I use `return`  in the if statement, foreach keeps executing and the rest of the function is also executed. I came up with this:

```
function F()
{
      $failed = $false
      $something | Foreach-Object {
           if ($_ -eq "foo"){
                $failed = $true
                break
           }
      }
      if ($failed){
          return
      }

      # do other stuff
}
```

I basically introduced a sentinel variable holding if I broke out of the loop or not. **Is there a cleaner solution?**

Comment: Depending on what `$something` is, you could use the `foreach` statement instead of the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet and use `return`...

Answer (score 0):

Any help?

```
function F()
{
  Trap { Return }
  $something |
    Foreach-Object {
     if ($_ -eq "foo"){ Throw }
     else {$_}
    }
  }

 $something = "a","b","c","foo","d","e"   

 F
 'Do other stuff'
a
b
c
Do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your specific requirements, but I think you can simplify this by looking at it a different way.  It looks like you just want to know if *any* `$something == "foo"` in which case this would make things a lot easier:

```
if($something ? {$_ -eq 'foo')) { return }
```

? is an alias for [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx).  The downside to this is that it will iterate over *every* item in the array even after finding a match, so...

If you're indeed searching a string array, things can get even simpler:

```
if($something -Contains 'foo') { return }
```

If the array is more costly to iterate over, you might consider implementing an [equivalent of the LINQ "Any" extension method in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22090065/251983) which would allow you to do:

```
if($something | Test-Any {$_ -eq 'foo'}) { return }
```

As an aside, while exceptions in the CLR aren't [that costly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c), using them to direct procedural flow [is an anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl) as it can lead to code that's hard to follow, or, put formally, it violates the [principal of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).