# Scriptblock does not get pipeline variable binding when passed as argument to module function

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-4.0, powershell-module

I'm trying to put [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499466/powershell-equivalent-of-linq-any):

```
function Test-Any {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($EvaluateCondition,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $ObjectToTest)
    begin {
        $any = $false
    }
    process {
        if (-not $any -and (& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest)) {
            $any = $true
        }
    }
    end {
        $any
    }
}
```

into a module. I just created a new module, the my-scripts.psm1 file, which contains just the above function and import it with `Import-Module <absolute path>`.

The problem is that if I use the function from the module `1..4 | Test-Any { $_ -gt 3 }` returns false, because `$_` is not set to the value from the pipe.

If I define the function normally in a script and use it from there it works as expected (with $_ getting assigned the integer values).

This happens with PowerShell v4.0 under Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks to @PetSerAl's help, there's now a robust and optimizing (exits pipeline as soon as the test succeeds) version of this function in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34800670/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer of user4003407](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33240383/3982562) did solve my problem, but I don't find the examples very intuitive. So I'm writing this solution mainly to add an additional example.

I had the following function defined in my `MyHelpers.psm1` file which was causing issues:

```
function ConvertTo-HashTable {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject,
    [scriptblock] $Key = { $InputObject },
    [scriptblock] $Value = { $InputObject }
  )

  begin { $HashTable = @{} }
  process { $HashTable.Add((& $Key), (& $Value)) }
  end { $HashTable }
}
```

On usage:

```
Import-Module 'ExchangeOnlineManagement'
Import-Module 'MyHelpers'

$UserLookup = Get-User | ConvertTo-HashTable -Key { $_.Sid }
```

I got the error:

> EXCEPTION: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"

Because `$_` was not bound correctly, thus returning `$null` from the scriptblock.

To fix this I used [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3) to correctly bind `$_`, as suggested by the [answer of user4003407](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33240383/3982562). So I changed the definition to:

```
function ConvertTo-HashTable {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject,
    [scriptblock] $Key = { $InputObject },
    [scriptblock] $Value = { $InputObject }
  )

  begin { $HashTable = @{} }
  process {
    $HashTable.Add(
      ($InputObject | ForEach-Object $Key),
      ($InputObject | ForEach-Object $Value)
    )
  }
  end { $HashTable }
}
```

I went for `$InputObject | ForEach-Object $Key` instead of `ForEach-Object $Key -InputObject $InputObject`, because I prefer the way it reads, but both should do the job.

If you're looking for a shorter solution you could also use its alias `%`, (`$InputObject | % $Key`), but the linter I'm using doesn't recommend it ([AvoidUsingCmdletAliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/avoidusingcmdletaliases?view=ps-modules)) so I went with the full cmdlet name.

Comment: I've done a whole lot of PowerShell since asking the question and I still don't understand why exactly ForEach-Object helps here and what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

That command: `& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest` — does not bind anything to `$_`. In absence of a `param()` block in `ScriptBlock`, the value of `$ObjectToTest` will be bound to `$args[0]`.

```
$SB = {"`$_: '$_'; `$args[0]:'$($args[0])'"}
1..3 | ForEach-Object {& $SB ($_+3)}
```

Output:

```
$_: '1'; $args[0]:'4'
$_: '2'; $args[0]:'5'
$_: '3'; $args[0]:'6'
```

Why does referencing `$_` work: you simply reference the `$_` variable from the parent scope.

The value of `$_` that you see, is a current pipeline input object, passed to the `Test-Any` function.

```
function Test-Any {
    param($EvaluateCondition)
    process {
        "Test-Any `$_: '$_'"
        & $EvaluateCondition
    }
}
1..2 | %{3..4 | Test-Any {"EvaluateCondition `$_:'$_'"}}
```

Output:

```
Test-Any $_: '3'
EvaluateCondition $_:'3'
Test-Any $_: '4'
EvaluateCondition $_:'4'
Test-Any $_: '3'
EvaluateCondition $_:'3'
Test-Any $_: '4'
EvaluateCondition $_:'4'
```

When you define `Test-Any` in module scope, then variable `$_` with pipeline input to `Test-Any` also got defined in that module scope and was not available outside of it.

```
New-Module {
    function Test-Any {
        param($EvaluateCondition)
        process {
            "Test-Any `$_: '$_'"
            & $EvaluateCondition
        }
    }
} | Out-Null
1..2 | %{3..4 | Test-Any {"EvaluateCondition `$_:'$_'"}}
```

Output:

```
Test-Any $_: '3'
EvaluateCondition $_:'1'
Test-Any $_: '4'
EvaluateCondition $_:'1'
Test-Any $_: '3'
EvaluateCondition $_:'2'
Test-Any $_: '4'
EvaluateCondition $_:'2'
```

If you want to invoke a script block with some value bound to `$_`, then one way to do this would be:

```
ForEach-Object $EvaluateCondition -InputObject $ObjectToTest
```