# PowerShell: Invoking a script block that contains underscore variable

Tags: powershell

I normally do the following to invoke a script block containing `$_`:

```
$scriptBlock = { $_ <# do something with $_ here #> }
$theArg | ForEach-Object $scriptBlock
```

In effect, I am creating a pipeline which will give `$_` its value (within the `Foreach-Object` function invocation).

However, when looking at the source code of the `LINQ` module, it defines and uses the following function to invoke the delegate:

```
# It is actually surprisingly difficult to write a function (in a module)
# that uses $_ in scriptblocks that it takes as parameters. This is a strange
# issue with scoping that seems to only matter when the function is a part
# of a module which has an isolated scope.
# 
# In the case of this code:
# 1..10 | Add-Ten { $_ + 10 }
#
# ... the function Add-Ten must jump through hoops in order to invoke the
# supplied scriptblock in such a way that $_ represents the current item
# in the pipeline.
#
# Which brings me to Invoke-ScriptBlock.
# This function takes a ScriptBlock as a parameter, and an object that will
# be supplied to the $_ variable. Since the $_ may already be defined in
# this scope, we need to store the old value, and restore it when we are done.
# Unfortunately this can only be done (to my knowledge) by hitting the
# internal api's with reflection. Not only is this an issue for performance,
# it is also fragile. Fortunately this appears to still work in PowerShell
# version 2 through 3 beta.
function Invoke-ScriptBlock {
[CmdletBinding()]

    param (
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
        [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Object]$InputObject
    )

    begin {
            # equivalent to calling $ScriptBlock.SessionState property:
            $SessionStateProperty = [ScriptBlock].GetProperty('SessionState',([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic,Instance'))
            $SessionState = $SessionStateProperty.GetValue($ScriptBlock, $null)
        }
    }
    process {
        $NewUnderBar = $InputObject
        $OldUnderBar = $SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue('_')
        try {
            $SessionState.PSVariable.Set('_', $NewUnderBar)
            $SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($SessionState, $ScriptBlock, @())
        }
        finally {
            $SessionState.PSVariable.Set('_', $OldUnderBar)
        }
    }
}
```

This strikes me as a bit low-level.  Is there a recommended, safe way of doing this?

Comment: Alternative is to add a param block on the fly: ``$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("param(`$_)$ScriptBlock")``

Comment: Mathias' comment should be an answer. This is exactly how I would have handled it.

Comment: How does this differ from `$ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext($null, (New-Object PSVariable '_',$value), $null)` --- just asking.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sergey_babkins_blog/archive/2014/10/30/calling-the-script-blocks-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke scriptblocks with the ampersand. No need to use Foreach-Object.

```
$scriptblock = {## whatever}
& $scriptblock

@(1,2,3) | % { & {write-host $_}}
```

To pass parameters:

```
$scriptblock = {write-host $args[0]}
& $scriptblock 'test'

$scriptBlock = {param($NamedParam) write-host $NamedParam}
& $scriptBlock -NamedParam 'test'
```

If you're going to be using this inside of Invoke-Command, you could also usin the $using construct.

```
$test = 'test'
$scriptblock = {write-host $using:test}
```

Comment: Please read the question again.  I already know that.  I am talking about special script-blocks which contain `$_` variable.

Comment: I did read your question and tested it. Regardless of the scriptblock containing the pipeline variable, it works the same. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It will not work, if you have to jump between modules. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33232360)

Comment: On my computer, `& { $_ } 10` returns nothing but `& { param($x) $x } 10` correctly returns the value 10.  I am asking about the recommended invoking of pipeline variable-ed (`$_`) script-blocks.

Comment: I see. You are asking about passing parameters into scriptblocks? That's a different story altogether. No need to downvote my answer based on your misunderstanding of the terminology. I've updated my answer.