# Check if IEnumerable is empty in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, ienumerable

Is there a native PowerShell way to test, if `IEnumerable` is empty?

I know I can call [`Linq.Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) like this:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Any($enumeration)
```

But I hope that there's a more native way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171836/discussion-on-question-by-martin-prikryl-check-if-ienumerable-is-empty-in-powers).

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1499466/45375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **there is *no* PowerShell-native way in Windows PowerShell / as of PowerShell (Core) v7.2**, and while **`[Linq.Enumerable]::Any()` is at least *concise*, it can *break* in various scenarios and *doesn't operate lazily* in PowerShell**:

```sh
# These invocations with various *PowerShell* enumerables all FAIL with
# 'Cannot find an overload for "Any" and the argument count: "1"'
foreach ($enumerable in 1.5, $null, (& {}), (1,2,3)) {
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Any($enumerable) # !! BREAKS
}

# However, it does work with arrays that are *explicitly typed*.
[Linq.Enumerable]::Any([int[]] (1, 2)) # -> $true
```

- Now, `1.5`, `$null` and `& {}`do *not* implement `[IEnumerable]` (`[System.Collections.IEnumerable]` or a generic counterpart), but **in the world of PowerShell *everything* is enumerable**, even *scalars* and `$null`, but the latter only in the *pipeline*, not with `foreach`. The notable exception is the "collection null" value, a.k.a. "AutomationNull" whose sole purpose is to signal that there's *nothing* to enumerate (and as such you could argue that, as a special enumeration case, it *should* implement `[IEnumerable]`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375).
- However, `1, 2, 3` *does* implement `[IEnumerable]`: it is a regular PowerShell array of type `[object[]]`; while you can fix this particular case with - curiously - an explicit `[object[]]` cast, it is obviously not a general solution, as potential conversion to an *array* forces full enumeration - see the bottom section for more information.
- Bringing better LINQ integration to PowerShell in the future is the subject of [GitHub issue #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226).

**A robust - but obscure and non-lazy - PowerShell-native-features-only solution** that handles all of the above cases would be (PSv4+):

```sh
# Returns $true if $enumerable results in enumeration of at least 1 element.
# Note that $null is NOT considered enumerable in this case, unlike 
# when you use `$null | ...`
$haveAny = $enumerable.Where({ $true }, 'First').Count -ne 0

# Variant with an example of a *filter* 
# (Find the first element that matches a criterion; $_ is the object at hand).
$haveAny = $enumerable.Where({ $_ -gt 1000 }, 'First').Count -ne 0
```

The above is:

- not exactly obvious and therefore hard to remember.
- more importantly, **this approach cannot take advantage of the *pipeline*, which is how PowerShell implements *lazy (on-demand) enumeration***, and **this limitation applies to *all* .NET *method calls*, including `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any()`**.

That is, the enumerable - because a *method* is being called on it - must be an *expression*, and when PowerShell uses a command as an expression, including assigning to a variable, it *runs the command to completion* and implicitly *collects all output* in an `[object[]]`-typed array.

---

Therefore, a ***lazy* native PowerShell solution requires use of the *pipeline***, in the form of **a *hypothetical* `Test-Any` cmdlet**, which:

- receives input via the *pipeline*, in a *streaming* fashion (object by object).
- outputs `$true` if at least one input object is received.

<sup>Note: The examples use `$enumerable` as pipeline input for brevity, but only with actual calls to PowerShell commands, say , [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), would you get *streaming* (lazy) behavior.</sup>

```sh
# WISHFUL THINKING
$haveAny = $enumerable | Test-Any

# Variant with filter.
$haveAny = $enumerable | Test-Any { $_ -gt 100 }
```

The *unconditional* (filter-free) variant of `Test-Any` can be emulated efficiently via a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-First 1`

```sh
$haveAny = 1 -eq ($enumerable | Select-Object -First 1).Count
```

`Select-Object` can short-circuit pipeline input, taking advantage of an exception type that is *private* in Windows PowerShell and as of PowerShell (Core) v7.2. That is, there is **currently no way for user code to *stop a pipeline on demand***, which the `Test-Any` cmdlet would need to do in order to work efficiently (in order to prevent full enumeration):

- A long-standing feature request can be found [in GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).
- An **efficient, lazy `Test-Any` implementation that works around the limitation through use of a *private* PowerShell type** can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800670/45375), courtesy of [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral); aside from relying on a private type, you also incur an on-demand compilation performance penalty on *first* use in a session.
- In a similar vein, [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834) asks that the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)'s advanced features be brought to its pipeline-based equivalent, the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `where`), which would then allow a solution such as:

  ```sh
  # WISHFUL THINKING
  $haveAny = 1 -eq ($enumerable | where { $_ -gt 1000 } -First).Count
  ```

---

**Optional reading: Use of `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any($enumerable)` with PowerShell arrays**

`1, 2, 3` (often represented as `@(1, 2, 3)`, which is unnecessary, however) is an instance of an `[object[]]` array, PowerShell's default array type.

It is unclear to me why you cannot pass such arrays to `.Any()` *as-is*, given that it does work with an explicit cast to the *same type*: `[Linq.Enumerable]::Any([object[]] (1,2,3)) # OK`

Finally, an array constructed with a *specific* type can be passed as-is too:
`$intArr = [int[]] (1, 2, 3); [Linq.Enumerable]::Any($intArr) # OK`

If anyone knows why you cannot use an `[object[]]` array in this context *without an explicit cast* and whether there's a good reason for that, please let us know.