# Unexpected Behaviour with Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I just came across an unexpected behaviour of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object?view=powershell-7) which I couldn't find any explanation for:

```
$foo = $null | Where-Object {$false}
$foo -eq $null
> True


($null, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 1

($foo, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 1


($null, $null, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 1

($foo, $foo, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 0
```

If the condition of `Where-Object` is false, `$foo` should be `$null` (which appears to be correct).

However, piping `$foo` at least twice before any value into the pipeline seems to break it.

What is causing this?

---

Other inconsistencies:

```
($foo, $null, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 1

($foo, $null, $foo, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 0

($null, $foo, $null, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 1

($foo, 1, $foo, $foo | Measure-Object).Count
> 1

($null, $foo, $null, $foo, 1 | Measure-Object).Count
> 0
```

Comment: `$foo` is not precisely `$null`, which can be verified by checking `$foo.psbase` (a true `$null` gives nothing for `.psbase`). This is the runtime doing something wonky with wrapping objects.

Comment: Clearer perhaps is `$foo -is [psobject]`, which is `$True` for `... | Where-Object {$False}` and `$False` for `$null`. It's a `PSObject` that implicitly converts to `$null`, but not with perfect transparency.

Comment: See also this SO Q&A. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396721/in-powershell-why-is-null-lt-0-true-is-that-reliable/66397251#66397251

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- Not all apparent `$null` values are the same, as [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s comments indicate: **PowerShell has *two* types of null that situationally behave differently** - see the next section.
- Additionally, you're seeing **perhaps surprising [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) behavior and a *pipeline bug*** - see the bottom section.

  - It's best to eliminate `Measure-Object` from your test commands and simply invoke `.Count` *directly* on your arrays; e.g. (the simplest way to create the type of null as in your question is: `$foo = & {}`):

    - `($foo, $null, 1).Count` yields `3`
    - `($null, $foo, $null, $foo, 1).Count` yields `5`
  - As you can see, both types of null (discussed below) properly become *elements* of an array.

---

**There are *two distinct kinds of null values* in PowerShell**:

- There's bona fide ***scalar* null** (corresponding to `null` in C#, for instance).

  - This null is contained in the automatic `$null` variable.
  - .NET methods may return it. (While PowerShell code may output it too, doing so is best avoided).
- There's also the ***enumerable* "collection null"** (also called "AutomationNull", based on its class name), which is technically the [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton, which is itself a `[psobject]` instance.

  - This value is technically output by the pipeline when *PowerShell commands* (both binary cmdlets and PowerShell scripts/functions) produce *no output*.
  - **The simplest way to get this value is with `& {}`** , i.e. by executing an empty script block; of course, you can also use `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` explicitly).

Unfortunately, **the collection null value is nontrivial to distinguish from the scalar null**, as of PowerShell 7.2:

- [GitHub issue #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465) proposes allowing detection of collection null via `$var -is [AutomationNull]` *in a future PowerShell version*.
- For now, there are several **workarounds** for **testing whether a given value `$var` contains collection null**; perhaps the simplest (but non-obvious) is:

  - `$null -eq $var -and $var -is [psobject]` is `$true` only if `$var` contains the collection null value, because only collection null is technically an object.

**Behavioral differences**:

- **In *expression* contexts and in *parameter binding***, there is no difference in that **collection null is implicitly converted to `$null`**.

  - Note that this means that you cannot pass collection null as an *argument* - see the discussion in [GitHub issue #9150](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9150).
  - The ***exception* in the context of expressions** is the LHS of operators that support *collections* as their LHS: they treat collection null as an empty collection and therefore evaluate to an *empty array* (`@()`) rather than `$null`:

    - E.g., `$var -replace 'foo' | ForEach-Object { 'hi' }`  prints `'hi'` only if `$var` is scalar `$null`, not with with collection null, because the `-replace` operation then outputs an empty array, which sends nothing through the pipeline.
    - See [GitHub issue #3866](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3866).
- **In the *pipeline***:

  - Scalar **`$null` *is* sent through the pipeline - it behaves like a single object**: `$null | ForEach-Object { '$_ is $null? ' + ($null -eq $_) }` prints `'$_ is $null? True'`;
  - **Collection null is *not* sent through the pipeline - it behaves like a collection *without elements***; that is, just like `@() | ForEach-Object { 'hi' }` (sending an empty array), `& {} | ForEach-Object { 'hi' }` sends nothing through the pipeline, because *there is nothing to enumerate*, and therefore never outputs `'hi'`.
  - Curiously, by contrast, **in a [`foreach` loop *statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach)** (as opposed to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*) scalar `$null` too is *not* enumerated and the loop body is never entered in the following (ditto for collection null):
    `foreach ($i in $null) { 'hi' }`

---

**`Measure-Object` and pipeline problems:**

- **`Measure-Object` generally *ignores `$null` values***, presumably *by design*.

  - This is discussed in [GitHub issue #10905](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10905), which proposes introducing an `-IncludeNull` switch to support considering `$null` values on an *opt-in* basis. (The default behavior will not change so as not to break backward compatibility.)
- However, **you've discovered an outright *bug* in PowerShell's *pipeline* with respect to *multi-object input involving *collection nulls**** (as of PowerShell 7.1.2) , which `Measure-Object` only *surfaces*, as you've noted yourself:

  - On encountering a *second* collection null in multi-object input, sending objects through the pipeline unexpectedly *stops*:

    - E.g., `(1, (& {}), 2, (& {}), 3, 4, 5 | Measure-Object).Count` yields just `2`: only `1` and `2` are counted (the collection nulls themselves are *not* sent through the pipeline), because the second collection null unexpectedly stops enumeration, so that the remaining objects - `3`, `4`, and `5` - aren't even sent to `Measure-Object`.
  - See [GitHub issue #14920](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14920).

Answer (score 0):

To add to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s very detailed and much appreciated answer, I want to share the workaround I used:

```
$numbers = 3, 42, 7, 69, 13
$no1 = $numbers | Where-Object {$_ -eq 1}
$no2 = $numbers | Where-Object {$_ -eq 2}
$no3 = $numbers | Where-Object {$_ -eq 3}
```

Instead of piping the variables directly to `ForEach-Object`, which produces no output ... :

```
$no1, $no2, $no3 | ForEach-Object {$_}
>
```

... pipe the variable *names* to `ForEach-Object` and make use of `Get-Variable` to get the desired result:

```
'no1', 'no2', 'no3' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Variable $_).Value}
> 3
```

Comment: Thanks; a simpler - but also obscure - workaround is: `[array] $no1 + $no2 +  $no3 | ForEach-Object {$_}`. By using array concatenation, the collection-null values are effectively eliminated.