# Powershell access caller scope variables across modules

Tags: powershell, scope

I have the following method declared in a module I've called `Common.psm1`:

```
function Test-Any ([ScriptBlock]$FilterScript = $null)
{    
    begin {
        $done = $false
    }
    process { 
        if (!$done)
        {
            if (!$FilterScript -or ($FilterScript | Invoke-Expression)){
                $done = $true
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        $done
    }
}
Set-Alias any Test-Any -Scope Global
```

Now in another module, I have the following validation:

```
    $id = 1
    if($notifications | any { $_.Id -eq $id })
    {
        # do stuff here
        return
    }
```

I receive the following error:

> Invoke-Expression : The variable '$id' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.

The interesting thing is that if I move the `Test-Any` definition to the calling module, it works like a charm.

How can I make this work without copying `Test-Any` to my other modules and without changing this syntax:

```
if($notifications | any { $_.Id -eq $id })
```

**EDIT 1:**
There seems to be some debate about whether or not my code *should* work.  Feel free to try this on your own machine:

```
function Test-Any ([ScriptBlock]$FilterScript = $null)
{    
    begin {
        $done = $false
    }
    process { 
        if (!$done)
        {
            if (!$FilterScript -or ($FilterScript | Invoke-Expression)){
                $done = $true
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        $done
    }
}
Set-Alias any Test-Any -Scope Global

$id = 3

$myArray = @(
    @{Id = 1},
    @{Id = 2},
    @{Id = 3},
    @{Id = 4},
    @{Id = 5},
    @{Id = 6},
    @{Id = 7},
    @{Id = 8}
)
$myEmptyArray = @()

$myArray | any #returns true
$myArray | any {$_.Id -eq $id} #returns true
$myEmptyArray | any #returns false
$myEmptyArray | any {$_.Id -eq $id} #returns false
```

**EDIT 2:**
I just discovered that you only encounter this issue, when `Test-Any` resides in one loaded module and the calling code resides in a second module using `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`.  If you turn off StrictMode, you don't get the error, but it also doesn't work.

**EDIT 3:**
Needless to say this works perfectly fine:

```
    $sb = [Scriptblock]::Create("{ `$_.Id -eq $id }")
    if($notifications | any $sb)
```

But seriously takes away from the simplicity and intuitiveness I am trying to obtain

Comment: Have you looked into `Export-ModuleMember`? Given the scenario,  you can specify the scope level of a variable as well, if I'm not misunderstanding something.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This is a PowerShell Advanced Function.  You can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2).  Each iteration is processed in the `process` block

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am using `Export-ModuleMember` to export the method `Test-Any` but I don't want to use it to export `$id` since that will quickly become messy if I have to export a variable each time I use `any`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the point is when you use Advanced Functions, you don't need to declare `ValueFromPipeLine` because it already processes each iteration in the `process` block.  Give it a try, copy my code in the same module and debug it.  You will see that each item is properly piped in.  While the code in `begin` and `end` only execute once, the code in `process` executes for each item piped in.

Comment: @saml you're right, my bad. I see the point of what you're trying to do now. I have tried saving the function in a module and after restarting session calling `import-module` on the script with the `if` condition and it works fine. I'm not seeing that error you get.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no worries, I just learnt about Advanced Functions today myself.  So I was able to confirm what you mentioned.  If `Test-Any` is in a module, and you import the module, then it works.  But if the calling code resides in its own module as well, and then you call the function that calls `Test-Any` that is when it fails.

Comment: Ok, so, what Abraham said was right. On the second script, the results from `if($notifications | any { $_.Id -eq $id }) ...` would need to be stored in a variable and exported using `Export-ModuleMember`

Comment: The problem is that $id is a local function variable.  That means I'd have to export this variable each time the function is called.  I'm hoping for another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (which, when possible, [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)) implicitly *recreates* the script block passed from the *caller's* scope, via its *string representation*, in the context of the *module*, which invalidates any references to the caller's state in the script-block code (because modules generally don't see an outside caller's state, except for the *global* scope).

The solution is to execute the script block *as-is*, but provide it pipeline input as passed to the module function:

```
# Note: New-Module creates a *dynamic* (in-memory only) module,
#       but the behavior applies equally to regular, persisted modules.
$null = New-Module {
  function Test-Any ([ScriptBlock] $FilterScript)
  {    
      begin {
          $done = $false
      }
      process { 
          if (!$done)
          {
              # Note the use of $_ | ... to provide pipeline input
              # and the use of ForEach-Object to evaluate the script block.
              if (!$FilterScript -or ($_ | ForEach-Object $FilterScript)) {
                  $done = $true
              }
          }
      }
      end {
          $done
      }
  }
  
}

# Sample call. Should yield $true
$id = 1
@{ Id = 2 }, @{ Id = 1 } | Test-Any { $_.Id -eq $id }
```

Note: The `Test-Any` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800670/45375) uses a similar approach, but tries to *optimize* processing by stopping further pipeline processing - which, however, comes at the expense of incurring an on-demand compilation penalty the first time the function is called in the session, because - as of PowerShell 7.2 - you cannot (directly) stop a pipeline on demand from user code - see [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

Comment: This is it!  I've been trying to break it and aside from `$null | any` returning `True` (which is a whole other issue) it works exactly as I hoped!  You are a gentleman and a scholar.  And the explanation to boot!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @saml; my pleasure. Please also see my update re on-demand stopping of the pipeline. As for `$null` being considered "something" in the pipeline: it may be surprising, but note that PowerShell has its own definition of "nothing", which is "AutomationNull" (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375).