# Powershell - add extra column called RoleUserA* inside CSV file

Tags: powershell

I want to add an extra, empty column called `RoleUserA*` to a CSV file, as attempted below. `RoleUserA*` is not an AD Attribute.

```sh
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties * | 
  Select givenName, sn, displayname, samaccountname, RoleUserA*, title |
    Export-Csv -Path "c:\tmp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Desired output:

```sh
givenName,sn,displayname,samaccountname,RoleUserA*,title
user01,sn1,User01 SN,user01,,specialist
user02,sn2,User02 SN,user02,,specialist
```

However, `RoleUserA*` isn't being added as a column.

Comment: As an aside: While seductively convenient, the [use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) is conceptually problematic and can lead to misconceptions.

Comment: Adding to mklement0's helpful comment, you should also consider querying only the necessary properties to avoid unnecessary overhead to your Domain Controllers. `-Properties givenName, sn, displayname, title` instead of `-Properties *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter of the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `select`) interprets its arguments as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).

Therefore, `RoleUserA*` looks for *existing properties* on the input objects whose name *starts with* `RoleUserA` - and simply adds *none* to the output objects if no existing property matches; a simple example:

```
# Because 'bar*' matches no existing properties, it is *ignored*.
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 } | Select-Object foo, bar*

foo
---
  1
```

While *escaping* `*` as `` `* `` (`` 'RoleUserA`*' ``) so that it is used *literally*, as a (non-existent, in this case) property name, *should* be possible, it unfortunately isn't as of PowerShell 7.2.2,<sup>[1]</sup> as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, and he also points to the solution that *does* work:

Use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), whose `Name` entry (shortened to `n` below) is always treated *literally*; using `{ $null }` as the `Expression` (`e`) entry script block creates the property with value `$null`:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -Properties * | 
  Select givenName, sn, displayname, samaccountname, @{n='RoleUserA*';e={ $null }}, title |
    Export-Csv -Path "c:\tmp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Note: In scripts used long-term, it's better to spell out the entry keys of the calculated property in full, i.e.:

```
@{ Name = 'RoleUserA*'; Expression = { $null } }
```

---

<sup>[1] This should be considered a bug, or at least needs documenting - see [GitHub issue #17068](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17068)</sup>

<sup>[2] Using just `{ }` - i.e. an *empty* [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), *almost* works the same, but it actually creates an "Automation Null" value (the [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton), which *in expressions* behaves the same as `$null`, but acts differently *in a pipeline* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375) for more information.
That said, in the context of converting to CSV this difference won't matter.</sup>