# Powershell missing array after conversion hashtable to json

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, hashtable, data-conversion

Working with Graph API and Intune. I create hash table in my script and covert it to JSON which POST to GraphAPI.
But in one case during conversion I lose array. Because of this GraphAPI does not want to accept JSON and returns error.

Case when conversion is correct:

```
$TargetGroupIDs = @('111', '222')
$AppAssignment = @{
  mobileAppAssignments = @{
  }
}

$AppAssignment.mobileAppAssignments = foreach ($GroupID in $TargetGroupIDs) {
  $Hash = [ordered]@{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment"
    intent        = "Required"
    settings      = $null
    target        = @{
      "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
      groupId       = "$GroupID"
    }
  }
  write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash)
}

$AppAssignment | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50
```

Output:

```
{
  "mobileAppAssignments": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment",
      "intent": "Required",
      "settings": null,
      "target": {
        "groupId": "111",
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment",
      "intent": "Required",
      "settings": null,
      "target": {
        "groupId": "222",
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I have one element in $TargetGroupIDs conversion is not correct:

```
$TargetGroupIDs = @('111')
$AppAssignment = @{
  mobileAppAssignments = @{
  }
}

$AppAssignment.mobileAppAssignments = foreach ($GroupID in $TargetGroupIDs) {
  $Hash = [ordered]@{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment"
    intent        = "Required"
    settings      = $null
    target        = @{
      "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
      groupId       = "$GroupID"
    }
  }
  write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash)
}

$AppAssignment | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50
```

Output:

```
{
  "mobileAppAssignments": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment",
    "intent": "Required",
    "settings": null,
    "target": {
      "groupId": "111",
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
    }
  }
}
```

Please note difference in brackets after mobileAppAssignments. In first case [], but in second case {}.

Could someone tell what I am missing in second case?

Comment: Surround your `foreach` loop with the array subexpression operator: `$AppAssignment.mobileAppAssignments = @(foreach ($GroupID in $TargetGroupIDs) { ... })`

Comment: Alternatively replace `foreach` by the `.ForEach` intrinsic method, which always outputs an array-like collection: `$AppAssignment.mobileAppAssignments = $TargetGroupIDs.ForEach{` and replace `$GroupID` by `$_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) have provided the crucial hint in the comments, but let me spell it out:

**To ensure that the output from your [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement is an *array*, enclose it in `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):**

```
$AppAssignment.mobileAppAssignments = @(
  foreach ($GroupID in $TargetGroupIDs) {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment"
      intent        = "Required"
      settings      = $null
      target        = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
        groupId       = "$GroupID"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

<sup>Also note that simplified syntax custom-object literal syntax (`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`).</sup>

`@(...)` ensures that an *array* (of type `[object[]]`) is returned, irrespective of how many objects, if any, the `foreach` statement outputs.

***Without* `@(...)`, the data type of the collected output depends on the *number of output objects*** produced by a statement or command:

- If there is *no* output object, the special "AutomationNull" value is returned, which signifies the absence of output; this special value behaves like an *empty collection* in enumeration contexts, notably the pipeline, and like `$null` in expression contexts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375) for more information; in the context at hand, it would be converted to a `null` JSON value.
- If there is *one* output object, it is collected *as-is*, as itself  - this is what you saw.
- Only with *two or more* output objects do you get an *array* (of type `[object[]]`).

Note: The **behavior above follows from the *streaming* behavior of the PowerShell pipeline / its success output stream**: object are emitted *one by one*, and needing to deal with *multiple* objects only comes into play if there's a need to *collect* output objects: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.

Comment: Thank for detailed response. I not only resolved my problem, but also understood root cause.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @Vindi4i; thanks for the feedback.