# Is it correct error (it looks that throw does not work)?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script:

```
$ErrorPreference = 'Stop'
$user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
if ($null -eq $user) {
    throw 'User and password are required'
} else {
    $password = (Get-Credential -credential $user).Password
    if ($null -eq $password) {
        throw 'Password is required'
    } else {
        $plainpassword = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", $password).Password
        $service = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Service -filter "name='myservice'"
        if ($null -ne $service) {
            [void]$service.change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $false, $user, $plainpassword)
        } else {
            throw 'Service was not installed properly'
        }
    }
}
```

and when I press "Cancel" in the dialog of credentials input, then the user and password must be `$null`. So, I test them on `$null`. But I get an error:

```
Get-Credential : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null.
At C:....ps1:6 char:45
+     $password = (Get-Credential -credential $user).Password
+                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Credential], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCredenti
   alCommand

Password is required
At C:....ps1:8 char:9
+         throw 'Password is required'
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Password is required:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Password is required
```

and I see `throw 'Password is required'` but at the same time I see:

```
Get-Credential : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null.
```

and I expect that if `$user` is `$null` then it should not happen and I would exit before this line even. Why this happen and how to handle this?

PS. It seems `$ErrorPreference = 'Stop'` is redundant, just to be sure...

Comment: $user will never be $null, because you do ```$user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name``` = so $user always contains the username of the caller. Also get-credential returns an credential object, don't filter the property password out of it. just do ```$credential = Get-Credential -credential $user``` then you can call later the method getNetworkCredential: ```$credential.getNetworkCredential()``` to get the password in cleartext

Comment: side note: this happens to me when I don't run powershell as admin (e.g. I run "enter-psSession someMachine -credential (get-credential -credential someDomain\otherUser)"); if I run powershell normally, I get error "Get-Credential : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```bash
# Get the current user's domain-qualified name, using whoami.exe for simplicity
# (same as [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name).
# (Alternatively, use "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME", or
#  if the domain prefix isn't needed just $env:USERNAME)
$user = whoami

# Prompt for the current user's password.
# Note the use of -UserName rather than -Credential.
# -Message is then unfortunately *required* in *Windows PowerShell*,
# but no longer in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName $user -Message 'Enter your credentials:'

# Abort, if the prompt was canceled (return value is $null)
# or an empty password was given (a [pscredential] instance was returned,
# but the length of its .Password property is 0).
if ($null -eq $cred -or $cred.Password.Length -eq 0) { throw "Password is required." }

# Get the plain-text password for the later WMI method call.
# !! THIS SHOULD GENERALLY BE AVOIDED.
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

# ... Make your WMI call
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Get-Credential -credential $user`

[`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential)'s **`-Credential` parameter** is a strange beast and **best avoided**, because it expects an argument that already *is* a `[pscredential]` instance as its argument.

Passing just a user *name* to `-Credential`, as you did, so as to pre-fill the username field, works in principle, but **causes a (statement-terminating) *error* when you *cancel* the dialog**, accompanied by a confusing error message:

- `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null` - this despite the fact that you clearly *did* pass an argument to `-Credential`.
- The reason for the error is that passing a mere user *name* to `-Credential` *itself* triggers a credential prompt, due to the `-Credential` parameter being decorated with the [`System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute) attribute, and this happens *before* `Get-Credential` receives the return value from that prompt:
- If that prompt is canceled, `$null` is returned, and the attempt to *then* bind `$null` to the `-Credential` parameter triggers the error.
- Conversely, if you pass a preexisting `[pscredential]` instance, *no prompt is displayed* and the instance is simply *passed through*.

**Use the `-UserName` parameter instead** (assuming you need to pre-fill a username in the prompt), which behaves more sensibly; unfortunately, for syntactic reasons, **in *Windows PowerShell* you *must* then *also* use the `-Message` parameter**, as shown above; fortunately, this is no longer a requirement in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

- If you cancel the dialog, `$null` is returned<sup>[1]</sup>, and no error occurs.

  - NOTE: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, `Get-Credential` no longer uses a *GUI* dialog to prompt, it prompts directly in the console window. You can no longer *cancel* such a prompt per se, but you can press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, which automatically terminates the *script as a whole*, however.
- Otherwise, a [`[pscredential]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) instance is returned, containing the username and the password as a [`[securestring]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString).

---

<sup>[1] Technically, there is *no output*, which PowerShell signals with a special singleton sometimes called "AutomationNull" - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410615/45375). However, in *expressions* such as `-eq` comparisons, it behave like `$null`.</sup>

Comment: Amazing job on explaining.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @AlexanderGonchiy, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Because that cmdlet has required params you have to wrap the call in a try catch block to catch that ParameterBindingException

```
$ErrorPreference = 'Stop'
$user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
if ($null -eq $user) {
    throw 'User and password are required'
} else {
    try {
        $cred = Get-Credential -Credential $user
        $password = ($cred.getNetworkCredential()).Password   
        $service = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Service -filter "name='myservice'"
        if ($null -ne $service) {
            [void]$service.change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $false, $user, $password)
        } else {
            throw 'Service was not installed properly'
        }
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]{
        throw 'Password is required'
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree Toni, I reworked it to have everything in the try catch and to use the getNetworkCredential method.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this on PowerShell 5 after updating to Windows 11 - quick fix is to use PowerShell 7 with:
`-Credential (Get-Credential -Credential username)`

It asks you to fill in password within in the command window