# Is there a way to stream data out faster from a large command?

Tags: performance, powershell, pipeline, memory-efficient

Let's say I'm using `get-childitem c:\*.* -recurse` and I am piping it. I have to wait for the whole get-childitem command to complete before the pipe handles it. There are exceptions such as `select -first 2` which magically stops the previous command. Anyhow is there a way to improve output so it write right away instead of soaking up a ton of ram? One idea I have is...(which i know won't work, but it gets the idea across)

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$(dir c:\*.* -recurse)")
```

I know this is a windows thing because Linux will work with data as soon as it shows up. But two different worlds, I know.

My biggest concern is ram usage...

Here is a great example

```
(1..10000000) | where {$_ -like "*543*"}
```

this takes my machine about 100 Seconds

where

```
(1..10000000).where({$_ -like "*543*"})
```

only took 25 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to wait for the whole get-childitem command to complete before the pipe handles it.

No: The **very point of PowerShell's pipeline is to process objects *one by one, as they become available*, thereby acting as a *memory throttle* that keeps memory use constant** irrespective of the size of the input collection.

- **Caveat**: Do NOT place [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), the *grouping operator* around the command whose output you send through the pipeline, as that will indeed collect that command's output in full, in memory, first.
- ***Cmdlets***, as PowerShell's native commands, inherently support this one-by-one streaming.

  - However, some cmdlets such as `Sort-Object` and `Group-Object` *must* collect all input in memory first<sup>[1]</sup>, as a *conceptual necessity* (e.g., you cannot produce sorted output until you've compared *all* items).<sup>Thanks, [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits).</sup>
  - Similarly, cmdlets such as `ConvertTo-Json`, which only emit a *single* output object, construct that one object from the entirety of the input collected up front.
- Similarly, stdout output from ***external programs*** is passed through the *line by line*, as the lines becomes available.
- You can turn an ***expression*** into a streaming command by enclosing it in `& { ... }`, but that is only useful if the expression hasn't already built the full collection of objects in memory; e.g.,
  `& { 1..10000000 } | ...` won't gain you anything, but
  `& { for ($i=0; $i -lt 10000000; ++$i) { $i } } | ...` would.<sup>[2]</sup>
- Ultimately, if the source cmdlet / program / expression doesn't itself emit output objects in a streaming fashion (one by one, as they're being produced), you're out of luck.

However, **what is indeed missing is the ability to *stop* pipeline processing *on demand*** - which currently only `Select-Object -First` can do - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800670/45375) of mine.
There's a longstanding [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821) that asks for a mechanism to stop a pipeline on demand.

---

As an aside: Using the PSv4+ [`.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays) is indeed faster than using the [`Where-Object` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (whose built-in alias is `where`), but `.Where()` invariably requires the collection that it operates on to have been loaded into memory in full beforehand.

However, the `.Where()` method *does* have the ability to stop processing remaining items by passing `'First'` as the 2nd argument, which stops after the first match; `'First'` is an instance of [`[System.Management.Automation.WhereOperatorSelectionMode]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.whereoperatorselectionmode); compare the performance of
`(1..1e6).Where({$_ -eq 10})` to that of
`(1..1e6).Where({$_ -eq 10}, 'First')`

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell does *not* use *temporary files* to ease the memory pressure the way the Unix `sort` utility does, for instance; my guess is that doing so is not really an option in PowerShell: PowerShell's ability to process live objects (rather than static strings) would present significant serialization / deserialization challenges were temporary file to be used.</sup>

<sup>[2] However, `1..10000000 | ...` and  `& { foreach ($i in 1..10000000) { $i } } | ...` *would* work: Uniquely among PowerShell's operators, `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) is implemented as a *lazy .NET enumerable*, which *direct* pipeline input and use in a `foreach` conditional can take advantage of.</sup>

Comment: You have a very very impressive grasp of powershell. Do you recommend any books? I'd trust your input over reviews. I want to know the fundamental inner workings (like how parentheses force full load into ram) etc... And also a very wide grasp on .net framework/objects/commands. I'm aware of the mountain ahead. But I write many scripts for large files. And if I can shave 30% off time by better code, I could save months of time annually

Comment: @RobertCotterman: There's the language spec, though it hasn't been updated since v3: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389 The only book I know (and have only read excerpts of) is https://www.manning.com/books/windows-powershell-in-action-third-edition Beyond that, trial and error are your friend (the official docs, unfortunately, aren't, though things are improving since both PowerShell and the docs have gone open-source) and, if you're adventurous, studying the source code: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: for those wondering, there isn't really a right answer to my question, it's more of an exploratory method of discovering how powershell works, Mklement0 made some amazing points as he always does.