# Using continue/return statement inside .ForEach() method - is it better to use foreach ($item in $collection) instead?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, return, continue

It's fairly well documented that foreach processing speed varies depending on the way a foreach loop is carried out (ordered from fastest to slowest):

1. `.ForEach()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#foreach)
2. [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.4) ($item in $collection) {}
3. $collection | [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.4) {}

- When working with (*very*) large collections, speed comparisons between #1 and #2 can be significant, and the overhead of piping makes #3 a non-candidate in those cases.
- #2 offers the `continue` statement, while #1 does not

  - *Please* correct/comment if this is inaccurate
- From what I've seen online and in real life, `return` is how to "`continue`" when using the `.ForEach()` method.

## My questions:

1. When the speed advantage of the `.ForEach()` method is too big to settle for `foreach` and you need to `continue`, what is the proper way to `continue` when using `.ForEach({})`?
2. What are the implications or gotcha's you should be aware of when using `return` inside the `.ForEach()` method?

Comment: not sure where are you getting your information from but `.ForEach` is not faster than `foreach`, in fact `.ForEach` is the worst of those three methods because it doesn't stream output.

Comment: https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/
https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-foreach/#The_foreach_Method

Those are a few sources.  I'm not sure that "worst of those three methods" would be accurate since producing output isn't always necessarily the goal of a foreach loop.

Comment: " since producing output isn't always necessarily the goal of a foreach loop", well `.ForEach` always produces output, no matter what as shown in my answer ;)

Comment: This is a good question because it shows research, regardless of whether what it presents is correct or not. Actual test results would have substantiated its claims.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...and the overhead of piping makes #3 a non-candidate in those cases.

Incorrect, the pipeline is very efficient, it's almost pair with `foreach` (fastest way in PowerShell to enumerate a collection). `ForEach-Object` is the inefficient one because it dot sources the scriptblock.

`.ForEach` is almost never a good a alternative, tests below clearly show that. In addition the output type is always a `Collection<T>`:

```bash
''.ForEach({ }).GetType()

#   Namespace: System.Collections.ObjectModel
#
# Access        Modifiers           Name
# ------        ---------           ----
# public        class               Collection<PSObject>...
```

`.ForEach` doesn't stream output, meaning that there is no way to exit early from the loop with `Select-Object -First`, **this also means higher memory consumption**.

```bash
Measure-Command {
    (0..10).ForEach({ $_; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 }) | Select-Object -First 1
} | ForEach-Object TotalSeconds

# 2.2637483
```

As for the 2nd question, `return` is the closest you can get to `continue` exiting early from the invocation, there are no gotchas there as long it is understood that it exits early from the current invocation and goes to the next item in the collection, however there is no real way to `break` the loop using `.ForEach`.

I believe it's already understood but, `break` and `continue` **should not be used outside of outside of a loop, `switch`, or `trap`**:

- [#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.4#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap)
- [#do-not-use-continue-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.4#do-not-use-continue-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap)

```
& {
    ''.ForEach({ break })
    'will never get here'
}

'or here'
```

If you're looking for performance you should rely on `foreach` or a scriptblock with a `process` block or function with a `process` block.

```bash
$range = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 1mb)
$tests = @{
    'foreach' = {
        foreach ($i in $args[0]) { $i }
    }
    '.ForEach()' = {
        $args[0].ForEach({ $_ })
    }
    'ForEach-Object' = {
        $args[0] | ForEach-Object { $_ }
    }
    'process block' = {
        $args[0] | & { process { $_ } }
    }
}

$tests.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Test = $_.Key
        Time = (Measure-Command { & $_.Value $range }).TotalMilliseconds
    }
} | Sort-Object Time

# Test              Time
# ----              ----
# foreach         103.96
# process block   918.04
# .ForEach()     3614.44
# ForEach-Object 9046.14
```

Comment: Depending on what the inner code is actually doing, ```… | foreach-object { … } -Parallel``` could offer better / worse performance characteristics as well, especially for high latency network operations that might dwarf the time spent on internal book-keeping overheads for the different approaches…

Comment: @mclayton I agree but I think doesn't apply to this question I think since it's about sequential loop. Or at least parallel was never mentioned by OP

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the helpful answer from [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) the pipeline *is* indeed very efficient and often underestimated as one doesn't incorporate where the data is actually coming from. For Santiago's performance testing it is conveniently presumed that the data is already in memory were he "preloads" the sample data (using a [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation) statement): `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 1mb)`
But that isn't required in the same way for a proper [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines).

Let's clear the air with an exaggerated example (which also covers your second question) where the `.foreach{}` method is clearly defeated by the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

- This takes almost **`1 second`**:

```
(0..1mb).ForEach{ if ($_ -eq 1) { return $_ } }
```

- Where this takes about **`43 milliseconds`**:

```
0..1mb | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -eq 1) { $_ } } | Select-Object -First 1
```

<sup>(**note:** To properly test the performance, you should start a new terminal session)</sup>

You might argue that this isn't a fair competition, because -aside from the fact that I am selecting the first occurrence¹- I load the whole array into memory (using the [grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#grouping-operator--)) for the method test.
But that is in fact exactly where this is about; it is comparing apples to oranges knowing that there is no easy way for the `.foreach{}` method to do otherwise, where ***[cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)s** are optimized for the pipeline* which includes dealing with the input (and output). Needless to mention that any meaningful function should at least have some input or output...

**Notes**

1. If your targeted search is further in the array/stream (than just `$_ -eq 1` in the examples), the performance difference will of cause get less. But than again, if your data doesn't come from memory (which is usually initially the case) but from a slower source as a file or a (remote) database, than you will see that the full pipeline solution performs as good (or better) even if you iterate through the whole range.

- For your second question, I would actually consider the [`.where({ ... }, 'first' )` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_array#where) instead of the `foreach{ ... }` method and the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) instead of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet which makes this question/answer very similar to: [Fastest Way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026)
- The [`Select-Object -First` affects the upstream commands by cheating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60791320/1701026) which also shows that the cmdlets interact with each other and therefore can't be easily (performance) measured alone

Bottom line:

> **For performance testing the pipeline you will need to compare your whole solution.**

I challenge anybody who blindly states that a `.foreach{}` method or `foreach ( ... )` statement is *generally* faster than the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet, to write (and performance test) a substitute for a common pipeline as:

```
Get-Content .\MyList.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq 'something') { $_ }
    } | Select-Object -First 1
```

Or excluding your second question:

```
Import-Csv .\Input.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.value -eq 'something') { $_.value = 'something else' }
    } | Export-Csv .\Output.csv
```

Because even it is often suggested to be faster:

- Any `.foreach{}` method or `foreach ( ... )` statement substitute, will likely perform less for these examples (or the difference is marginal)
- Any `.foreach{}` method or `foreach ( ... )` statement substitute will need more code which is likely more difficult to read (develop and maintain) taking the note from the [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) document in consideration:

> **Note**
> Many of the techniques described here aren't idiomatic PowerShell and may reduce the readability of a PowerShell script. Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise.

- Any `.foreach{}` method or `foreach ( ... )` statement substitute will likely consume more memory which could possibly lead to performance issues by itself if you reach the limits of computer's physicals memory
- And (as mentioned by [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)) as extra bonus, once you have setup a proper pipeline, it is a minor step (for PowerShell 7, just a single [`-Parallel` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#-parallel)) to possibly further boost your pipeline with parallel processing

Comment: I could read one of those articles until I saw _"This method provides faster performance than its older counterparts (the foreach statement and the ForEach-Object cmdlet)..."_, it is unfortunate how people get misinformed with articles and trust them without testing themselves.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the existing, helpful answers by addressing your specific questions:

> is it better to use `foreach ($item in $collection)` instead? [from the title]

Yes: **`foreach` by far performs best among the PowerShell enumeration techniques** and is the only one that **directly supports *stopping the enumeration on demand*, with `break`**.
See below for a detailed discussion of performance as well as syntax considerations.

> ...what is the proper way to **`continue`** when using `.ForEach({})`?

The proper way *is* to use **`return`**:

- In [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), such as ones passed to the `.ForEach()` *method* or to the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, `return` exits *that block only*.
- In the context of enumerating commands such as `.ForEach()` / `ForEach-Cmdlet`, this means that *processing continues with the next input object*, i.e. it ***resumes* the ongoing enumeration**.

This makes it analogous to the [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Continue) keyword, which *only* applies to a select few [*language statements*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords), such as [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68867996/45375) for details.

- Note that even though language statements use `{ ... }` blocks too, they aren't stand-alone *script-block objects* - the `{` and `}` purely act as *delimiters* for the enclosed code, so that a `return` in such a block exits *the enclosing function or script file (or stand-alone script block)* instead; a quick illustration of the difference:

  ```bash
  # Prints only 1 - the `return` exists the enclosing script block, 
  # not (just) the `foreach` statement.
  & { foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i; return }; 'never get here' }
  ```

---

However, I suspect you are instead looking for an **analog to the [*`break`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) keyword**, which *stops processing further input* on demand, i.e. ***stops* the ongoing enumeration**.

- As with `continue`, `break` only meaningfully works with a select few *language statements* - used outside such a context, PowerShell *looks up the call stack* for an enclosing loop / `switch` statement *anywhere* and breaks out of *that*; in the absence of one, the entire script (runspace) is exited.
- As of PowerShell (Core) 7.4.0, **there is NO `break` analog for `.ForEach()` or `ForEach-Object`** / the pipeline in general.

  - There is **NO workaround for `.ForEach()`**:

    - The only way to collect output from such a call is to let it *run to completion*, at which point it returns a *collection* of output object.
    - Hypothetically, in order for `.ForEach()` to support on-demand stoppage of the enumeration in the future, the script block would have to have a way to signal to the method that further enumeration should be stopped; this can *not* be done via *output* from the script block - because that is used for *results*.
    - Therefore, using **a `foreach` statement is your only well-performing alternative** - in fact, as has been noted, it is *faster* than `.ForEach()`
  - ***Suboptimal* workarounds for `ForEach-Object` / the pipeline in general**:

    - Use **[`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw)** in combination with **[`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)**
    - Alternatively, given the behavior of `continue` and `break` discussed above, you can use a **dummy loop** that you can **`break` out of** on demand.
    - If you **combine these workarounds with the *workaround for `ForEach-Object`'s inefficient implementation*<sup>[1]</sup> mentioned in [Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664377/45375)**,  you **get decent performance *even in the pipeline*** that surpasses even `.ForEach()` (but is still about an order of magnitude slower than a `foreach` *statement*)
    - Two simple examples - both only process and collect the *first* input object:

      ```bash
      # try / catch + throw
      $result = 
        try {  
          # Use `throw` to abort the pipeline.
          # Any objects emitted before that are still collected.
          1..100 | . { process { $_; throw } }
        } catch {}


      # Dummy loop + break
      $result = 
        do {
          # Use break to break out of the dummy loop.
          # Any objects emitted before that are still collected.
          1..100 | . { process { $_; break } }
        } while ($false)
      ```

---

##### Future considerations:

This **asymmetry between loop-like *statements* and the *pipeline* is unfortunate**:

- Stopping an enumeration on demand can be an important performance optimization.
- Outside of loop-like statements, this is currently only supported in two very specific scenarios:

  - As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, `.ForEach()`'s companion function, the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), has an optional second parameter to which `'First'` may be passed to stop enumeration once the first match has been found.
  - In the *pipeline*, [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-First` parameter is capable of stopping the enumeration after a given number of objects have been received.<sup>[2]</sup>

There's a **long-standing feature request that asks for user code to be able to stop upstream cmdlets on demand**:

- [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821)
- No decision as to how to implement this has been made as of this writing, but the two basic choices are:

  - Provide a new *cmdlet*.
  - Provide a new *keyword* (note that applying `break` and `continue` to script blocks in pipelines too is *not* an option, as it would break backward compatibility).
- Neither approach is a good fit for also bringing support for on-demand enumeration stoppage to the `.ForEach()` *method*, although a keyword-based approach, if named abstractly, would work better conceptually, e.g. `breakenum` or, to avoid confusion with `break`, `stopenum`

---

##### Performance considerations:

Given Santiago's pipeline-performance optimization based on a `process` block, the **performance ranking** is actually as follows, **based on an input collection that is *already in memory, in full***:

1. The `foreach` *statement* - the fasted *by far*.
2. The *pipeline* with the `process` block workaround, to compensate for the inefficient implementation of `ForEach-Object`, roughly *one order of magnitude slower*.
3. The `.ForEach()` *method*, roughly *two orders of magnitude slower*.
4. The `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, roughly *two orders of magnitude slower, and around 50% slower than `.ForEach()`*.

Note:

- The *rough* relative performance qualifiers are based on experiments with processing 1 million input objects and capturing the output in a variable, in [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4.0 (built on .NET 8), on both macOS and Windows. (In *Windows PowerShell*, `foreach` is noticeably slower than in PowerShell (Core), though still about 5 times faster than the `process` block solution).
- There is *one* case in which `.ForEach()` is slower than `ForEach-Object`, but it is *atypical*: if you output results *directly to the host (console)*.

---

##### Memory-usage / output-timing considerations - collect-in-full vs. streaming behavior:

- `ForEach-Object`:

  - As a *cmdlet*, it integrates naturally with PowerShell's [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) and its ***streaming* behavior**: `ForEach-Object` *receives* input objects via the pipeline *one by one* and emits its output objects one by one, with a downstream cmdlet receiving these objects *as soon as they're being emitted* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852476/45375) for background information.
- `.ForEach()` (and `.Where()`):

  - On **input**:

    - They *invariably* collect their input in full, up front, even when operating on a *lazy .NET enumerable*.
  - On **output**:

    - They *invariably* build up a collection of results method-internally first, and only *then* product output, namely that collection<sup>[3]</sup> as a whole; see also the next section.
- The `foreach` statement:

  - On **input**:

    - It too collects its input in full, up front, *except* when operating on an expression returning a *lazy .NET enumerable*, which notably includes - uniquely among PowerShell's operators - `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-); e.g. (note that `1e7` is short for `10000000`, i.e. 10 million):

      ```bash
      # Outputs 1 and finishes almost instantly, because the input
      # is a lazy .NET enumerable that is enumerated as such.
      foreach ($i in [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(1, 1e7)) { $i; break }

      # Ditto for `..`, the range operator.
      # NOTE: It is the ONLY PowerShell operator that does that.
      foreach ($i in 1..1e7) { $i; break }

      # Output from PowerShell *commands* as well as from other operators
      # *is* collected up front:

      # Takes a long time, because the Write-Output output is collected first.
      foreach ($i in Write-Output (1..1e7)) { $i; break }

      # Ditto, for the results of the -replace operation.
      foreach ($i in 1..1e7 -replace '^', '+') { $i; break }
      ```
  - On **output**:

    - It *streams* its output, as a cmdlet does, but you can only take advantage of that *if you invoke it enclosed in a script block*, via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) or `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-); e.g.:

      ```bash
      # Outputs 1 and finishes almost instantly, because the `foreach`
      # output is streamed (and 1..1e6 is enumerated lazily).
      & { foreach ($i in 1..1e7) { $i } } | Select-Object -First 1
      ```
    - By contrast, enclosure in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), or `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - with any enclosed statement(s) - invariably results in up-front collection of the output, in full; e.g.:

      ```bash
      # Outputs 1 only after a long time, because $(...) caused
      # up-front collection.
      $(foreach ($i in 1..1e7) { $i }) | Select-Object -First 1
      ```

---

##### Reasons to use or avoid `.ForEach()` / `.Where()`:

Given the faster alternatives, are there still benefits to `.ForEach()` and `.Where()`?

- **Downsides**:

  - Both `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` *always* emit a *collection*,<sup>[3]</sup> even if there's only *one* output object.

    - Given PowerShell's automatic enumeration behavior in the pipeline and its [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature, that *will often not matter in practice*, though it is more likely to be a problem with `.Where()` in combination with `'First'`; e.g.:

      ```bash
      # Breaks, because the collection returned cannot bind
      # to the [int] parameter; requires [0]
      & { 
        param([int] $Number)
      }  (1, 5, 10).Where({ $_ -ge 5 }, 'First')
      ```
  - Due to the specific type of the collection,<sup>[3]</sup> its elements are wrapped in *typically* invisible `[psobject]` instances, which is not only unnecessary, but can have side effects.

    - Again, it will often not matter in practice and never *should*, but these meant-to-be-invisible wrappers do situationally result in different behavior - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).
    - *Method syntax* - i.e., the need to use `(...)` around the argument list and to separate arguments with `,` - is not a natural fit for PowerShell (which uses *shell-like* invocation syntax), though for users with a programming background that is less likely to be an issue.
- **Upsides**:

  - As *method* calls, they can *directly* act as or take part in *expressions*. This allows you to do things such as:

    ```bash
    # Direct use as a command argument.
    Write-Output (1..3).ForEach({ $_ + 1 })

    # Direct use as pipeline input.
    (1..3).ForEach({ $_ + 1 }) | Write-Output
    ```

    - Note:

      - *Language statements* such as `foreach` can only act as as expressions in an *assignment*, and only *stand-alone*, e.g., `$results = foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i + 1 }` works, but direct use of `foreach` in the examples above would *not*.
      - To make language statements work as expressions in general, wrap them in `$(...)` or `@(...)` for *up-front collection* of their outputs, or in `& { ... }` or `. { ... }` to *stream* their output (something that `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` cannot do).
  - Additional features: Both `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` have features that their cmdlet counterparts, `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` do *not* support.

    - [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) notably supports stopping after the first or only returning the last match, as well as splitting the input collection *in two*; e.g.:

      ```bash
       # Returns right away, because 'First' stops enumeration after the
       # first match. 'Last' is available too.
       (1..1e6).Where({ $_ -eq 2 }, 'First')

       # Returns *two* collections
       $odd, $even = (1..10).Where({ $_ % 2 -eq 1 }, 'Split')
      ```

      - Bringing these powerful features to the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* too is the subject of [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834).
    - [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)'s additional features are less compelling, as expression-mode alternatives exists, but one feature is useful when member-access enumeration isn't available: the availability to efficiently collect property values from all elements of a collection; e.g.:

      ```bash
       # Returns a collection of all file lengths (sizes).
       # Note that (Get-ChildItem -File).Length - i.e. member-access enumeration -
       # is NOT an option here, because the array used to collect the
       # command output *itself* has a .Length property.
       (Get-ChildItem -File).ForEach('Length')
      ```

---

<sup>[1] See [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).</sup>

<sup>[2] It does this via a *non-public* exception type, which is why user code cannot take advantage of it.</sup>

<sup>[3]
Of type [`` System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1), with [`[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject)-typed elements.</sup>