# Powershell Removing rows from a CSV that matches values in a Separate CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

We are currently in the process of migrating files and at the end of each migration we need to produce a report of any file that doesn't get migrated. (Not all source files are migrated).

I produce a csv file that contains all files from the source and then another csv after the migration of all files that have been migrated.

I am running the below powershell script to remove any file from the source csv that has a value in the migrated file csv saving the source csv then repeating n the next row, but its taking an age to run. (I am guessing that because its checking each value in the migrated csv with each row in the source csv) 1 file has 77810 rows and the other has 88900 rows.

Is there any other way to do this to speed up the process as these files are tiny compared to some of the migrations.

```
import-csv -Path 'C:\Temp\CFP Didnts\Test\SPeopleMigratedFiles.csv' | foreach-object {
    $Fullpath = $($_.FullPath)
    $text = [regex]::escape($Fullpath)
 
    (Import-CSv 'C:\temp\CFP Didnts\Test\S People Commissioning Full Files.csv') |
        Where-Object{ $_.FullName -notmatch $text } |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\temp\CFP Didnts\Test\S People Commissioning Full Files.csv' -Force
}
```

In short what I need to end up with at the end is 1 csv which contains only values not present in the migrated files csv.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

It works but on a small migration (cvs1 contains 77810 rows and CSV2 contains 88900 rows) compared to other migrations its taking an age to run, but it does work just very very slow.

Comment: You're reading the csv per loop iteration, you're also overwriting it per loop iteration

Comment: Thanks I did this so it didn't keep adding duplicate rows to the end resulting output. Any ideas how to output the end result so it doesn't show duplicate rows? If that makes sense?

Comment: But full understand thus is why it's taking ages to run as it's looping through every row every time for each row.

Comment: Could you provide 2-3 example records from each of the .csv files?

Comment: Very, very slow should be an understatement since you're iterating about 6.9 billion items, and both reading and writing a file each time. I imagine it'd be faster to just do something like `$migrated = import-csv $csv1path; import-csv $csv2path | where-object {$_.FullName -notin $migrated.FullName} | Export-Csv $csv3path -NoType` That should generate a new CSV with only the differences.

Comment: You might want to read [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) to understand and resolve you performance issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you're reading the Csv `S People Commissioning Full Files.csv` per loop iteration and you're also overwriting it per loop iteration.

Assuming you're looking to filter out **`.FullPath` values** on `SPeopleMigratedFiles.csv` that are an exact match of **`.FullName` values** in `S People Commissioning Full Files.csv`, then `-notmatch` is not the right operator to use in this case as, combined with `regex.Escape`, it would be filtering out **partial matches too**.

The way you can improve your code in this case is using a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-8.0) and change `ForEach-Object` for a [ScriptBlock with a `process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.4), which provides faster enumeration and consumes less resources. For a performance comparison between these 2 techniques for enumerating collections see the results in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664377/15339544).

```bash
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\CFP Didnts\Test\S People Commissioning Full Files.csv' | & {
    begin {
        # Hashsets are collections of unique values
        $hash = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
            [string[]] (Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\CFP Didnts\Test\SPeopleMigratedFiles.csv').FullPath,
            [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    }
    process {
        # if the value of `.FullName` can be added to the Hashset
        if ($hash.Add($_.FullName)) {
            # it means the `SPeopleMigratedFiles.csv` does not contain it
            $_
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\CFP Didnts\Test\S People Commissioning Full Files.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```