# How does begin/process/end save the need for foreach? Still needed for the parameter isn't it?

Tags: powershell

I've understood that with begin/process/end the process section runs mutiple times, for each object in the pipeline. So if I have a function like this:

```
function Test-BeginProcessEnd {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$myName     
    )
    begin {}
    process {
        Write-Host $myName
    }
    end {}
}
```

I can pipe an array to it, like this, and it processes each object:

```
PS C:\> @('aaa','bbb') | Test-BeginProcessEnd
aaa
bbb
PS C:\>
```

But if I try to use the parameter in the command line, I can only pass it 1 string, so I can do:

```
PS C:\> Test-BeginProcessEnd -myName 'aaa'
aaa
PS C:\>
```

But I can't do:

```
PS C:\> Test-BeginProcessEnd -myName @('aaa','bbb')
Test-BeginProcessEnd : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'myName'. Cannot convert value to type
System.String.
At line:1 char:30
+ Test-BeginProcessEnd -myName @('aaa','bbb')
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-BeginProcessEnd], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Test-BeginProcessEnd
PS C:\>
```

Obviously I want the parameter usage to be the same as via the pipeline, so I have to change the function to be:

```
function Test-BeginProcessEnd
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$myNames      
    )
    begin {}
    process {
        foreach ($name in $myNames) {
            Write-Host $name
        }
    }
    end {}
}
```

So I've had to use foreach anyway, and the looping functionality of the Process section hasn't helped me.

Have I missed something? I can't see what it's good for! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Because of how binding pipeline input to parameters works in PowerShell (see below), **defining a parameter that accepts pipeline input *as well as* direct parameter-value passing of *arrays*:**

- indeed **requires looping inside the `process` block**
- invariably **wraps individual input objects received through the pipeline in a single-element array each**, which is inefficient.

**Defining your pipeline-binding parameters as a *scalar* avoids this awkwardness**, but **passing *multiple* inputs is then *limited to the pipeline*** - you won't be able to pass arrays as a *parameter argument*.<sup>[1]</sup>

This *asymmetry* is perhaps surprising.

---

When you define a parameter that accepts pipeline input, you get *implicit* array logic for free:

- With *pipeline input*, PowerShell calls your `process` block *once for each input object*, with the current input object bound to the parameter variable.
- By contrast, passing input as a *parameter value* only ever enters the `process` *once*, with the input as a whole bound to your parameter variable.

The above *applies whether or not your parameter is array-valued*: *each* pipeline input object *individually* is bound / coerced to the parameter's type exactly as declared.

---

To put this in concrete terms with your example function that declares parameter `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [string[]] $myNames`:

Let's assume an input array (collection) of `'foo', 'bar'` (note that the `@()` around array literals is normally not necessary).

- Parameter-value input, `Test-BeginProcessEnd -myNames 'foo', 'bar'`:

  - The `process` block is called *once*,
  - with input array `'foo', 'bar'` bound to `$myNames` *as a whole*.
- Pipeline input, `'foo', 'bar' | Test-BeginProcessEnd`:

  - The `process` block is called *twice*,
  - with `'foo'` and `'bar'` *each* coerced to `[string[]]` - i.e., a *single*-element array.

To see it in action:

```
function Test-BeginProcessEnd
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
      [string[]]$myNames      
    )
    begin {}
    process {
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "in process block: `$myNames element count: $($myNames.Count)"
      foreach ($name in $myNames) { $name }
    }
    end {}
}
```

```
# Input via parameter
>  Test-BeginProcessEnd 'foo', 'bar'
VERBOSE: in process block: $myNames element count: 2
foo
bar

# Input via pipeline
> 'foo', 'bar' | Test-BeginProcessEnd
VERBOSE: in process block: $myNames element count: 1
foo
VERBOSE: in process block: $myNames element count: 1
bar
```

---

#### Optional reading: Various tips re functions and pipeline input

- `begin`, `process`, `end` blocks may be used in a function whether or not it is an *advanced* function (cmdlet-like - see below).

  - If you only need the 1st or a certain number of objects from the pipeline, there is currently no way to exit the pipeline prematurely; instead, you must set a Boolean flag that tells you when to ignore subsequent `process` block invocations.
  - You can, however use an intervening, separate call such as `| Select-Object -First 1`, which efficiently exits the pipeline after the desired number of objects have been received.
  - The current inability to do the same from *user code* is the subject of [this suggestion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).
  - Alternatively, you can forgo a `process` block and use `$Input | Select-Object 1` inside your function, but, as stated, that will collect all input in memory first; another - also imperfect - alternative can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832628/45375) of mine.
- If you do *not* use these blocks, you can still optionally access pipeline input via the automatic `$Input` variable; note, however, that your function then *runs after ALL pipeline input has been collected in memory* (not *object by object* as with a `process` block).
- Generally, though, it pays to use a `process` block:

  - Objects can be *processed one by one, as they're being produced by the source command*, which has 2 benefits:

    - It makes processing more memory-efficient, because the source command's output doesn't have to be collected in full first.
    - Your function starts to produce output right away, without needing to wait for the source command to finish first.
  - Hopefully soon (see above), you'll be able to exit the pipeline once all objects of interest have been processed.
  - Cleaner syntax and structure: the `process` block is an implicit loop over all pipeline input, and you can selectively perform initialization and cleanup tasks in the `begin` and `end` blocks, respectively.
- It is easy to turn a function into an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced), however, which offers benefits with respect to supporting [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) such as `-ErrorAction`, and `-OutVariable` as well as detection of unrecognized parameters:

  - Use a `param()` block to declare the parameters and decorate that block with the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, as shown above (also, decorating an individual parameter with a `[Parameter()]` attribute *implicitly* makes a function an advanced one, but for clarity it's better to use `[CmdletBinding()]` explicitly).

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, you *can*, but only if you type your parameter `[object]` (or don't specify a type at all, which is the same).

However, the input array/collection is then bound *as a whole* to the parameter variable, and the `process` block is still only entered once, where you'd need to perform your own enumeration.

Some standard cmdlets, such as `Export-Csv`, are defined this way, yet they do *not* enumerate a collection passed via the `-InputObject` *parameter*, making direct use of that parameter effectively useless - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The `BEGIN`-`PROCESS`-`END` structure is used for scripts/advanced functions where (a) you want to be able to pipe data to it, and (b) there is stuff that you want to do before (`BEGIN`) and/or after (`END`) processing the entire set of data (as opposed to before or after each individual item that comes through the pipe). If you pass a single value to an advanced function that uses the `foreach` to be able to handle an array, it treats the single value as an array of one item; the pipe does this, in effect - except that with pipe, it doesn't need to reload the cmdlet for each item. This is, ultimately, why you can write scripts/advanced functions that can be used either in the pipeline or as 'standalone' processes. It is not that `PROCESS` causes the looping; it's that it enables the efficient processing of values coming in from the pipeline. If you want to handle multiple values passed to it by other than the pipeline, you need to manage the looping yourself  - as you've discovered.